# filtering nodes by degree in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, html, layout, graph, cytoscape.js

I have a cytoscape.js graph and i want to filter nodes by degree size. for example if node1 is only connected to node2 and node3 , when I select threshold 3 from filter, all nodes witch have less than 3 edges will be removed. now I have this problems:

1) how can I filter by degree? I know `var collection = cy.elements("node[weight > 2]");` select a collection and `cy.remove(collection);` will delete those nodes but how remove by number of connected edges?

2)after removing some nodes, its needed to rerun layout for better representation. I found a solution but it takes time roughly as big as before removing nodes. I tested this code :

code for adding node:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    try {

        cy.add({
                data: {
                    id: keys[i],
                    weight: i
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

code for layout:

```
var layout;
cy.ready(function () {
    layout = cy.layout({
        name: 'cose-bilkent',
        animate: false,
        padding: 100,
        nodeRepulsion: 20000,
        idealEdgeLength: 700,
        edgeElasticity: 10,
        numIter: 2500,
        initialEnergyOnIncremental: 0.01,
        ready: function () {
        }, // on layoutready
        stop: function () {
            cy.endBatch();
            var b64key = 'base64,';
            var b64 = cy.png().substring(cy.png().indexOf(b64key) + b64key.length);

            var imgBlob = b64toBlob(b64, 'image/png');
            saveAs(imgBlob, 'graph.png');


            alert(new Date().getTime() - n);
            n = new Date().getTime();
        }
    });
    layout.run();
});
```

and on button click I run this :

```
    var collection = cy.elements("node[weight > 2]");
    cy.remove( collection );
    layout.run();
```

but it takes 37sec for loading this graph with 3 nodes!!!