# Filtering graph by connectivity to a specific node in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

New to Cytoscape. I have a graph with dominant main network and some smaller networks unconnected to the main one that I want to remove.  Looking through the documentation I can't see an obvious solution to this.  I'm guessing maybe a custom approach is required that loops through all nodes, checks their graph distance from the most central node in the main cluster, and if this distance is undefined remove that node and all others it does connect to.  But keen to get a steer from others with more experience with the library.  Any advice is much appreciated.  I note [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51270021/filtering-nodes-by-degree-in-cytoscape-js) unanswered but related question.

Here is an example graph. Though I can't get working on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0t2yshn/) here is [working version](https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape.js-dagre/):

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>cytoscape-dagre.js demo</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
    <script src="cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>

    <style>
      #cy {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 999;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

        var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
          container: document.getElementById('cy'),

          boxSelectionEnabled: false,
          autounselectify: true,

          layout: {
            name: 'dagre'
          },

          style: [
            {
              selector: 'node',
              style: {
                'background-color': '#11479e'
              }
            },

            {
              selector: 'edge',
              style: {
                'width': 4,
                'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
                'line-color': '#9dbaea',
                'target-arrow-color': '#9dbaea',
                'curve-style': 'bezier'
              }
            }
          ],

          elements: {
            nodes: [
              { data: { id: 'n0' } },
              { data: { id: 'n1' } },
              { data: { id: 'n2' } },
              { data: { id: 'n3' } },
              { data: { id: 'n4' } },
              { data: { id: 'n5' } },
              { data: { id: 'n6' } },
              { data: { id: 'n7' } },
              { data: { id: 'n8' } },
              { data: { id: 'n9' } },
              { data: { id: 'n10' } },
              { data: { id: 'n11' } },
              { data: { id: 'n12' } },
              { data: { id: 'n13' } },
              { data: { id: 'n14' } },
              { data: { id: 'n15' } },
              { data: { id: 'n16' } }
            ],
            edges: [
              { data: { source: 'n0', target: 'n1' } },
              { data: { source: 'n1', target: 'n2' } },
              { data: { source: 'n1', target: 'n3' } },
              { data: { source: 'n4', target: 'n5' } },
              { data: { source: 'n4', target: 'n6' } },
              { data: { source: 'n6', target: 'n7' } },
              { data: { source: 'n6', target: 'n8' } },
              { data: { source: 'n8', target: 'n9' } },
              { data: { source: 'n8', target: 'n10' } },
              { data: { source: 'n11', target: 'n12' } },
              { data: { source: 'n12', target: 'n13' } },
              { data: { source: 'n13', target: 'n14' } },
              { data: { source: 'n13', target: 'n15' } },
            ]
          }
        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>cytoscape-dagre demo</h1>

    <div id="cy"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the filtering methods provided in the [docs](https://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/traversing), if you find some method better suited for this problem, just fiddle around with them until you get the right result. The important part here is the [.union()](https://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.union) and the [.not()](https://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.difference) method. You can use these to:

- traverse the graph in a controlled way, saving the important nodes on the way
- and then filter the collection to fit your needs

You mentioned not being able to get the jsfiddle to work, you can test the code below in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a7cusxmn/)

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "text-halign": "center",
        height: "60px",
        width: "60px",
        "border-color": "black",
        "border-opacity": "1",
        "border-width": "10px"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "n0"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n1"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n2"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n3"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n6"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n7"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n8"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n9"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n10"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n11"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n12"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n13"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n14"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n15"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n16"
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "n0",
          target: "n1"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n2"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n3"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n4",
          target: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n4",
          target: "n6"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n6",
          target: "n7"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n6",
          target: "n8"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n8",
          target: "n9"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n8",
          target: "n10"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n11",
          target: "n12"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n12",
          target: "n13"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n13",
          target: "n14"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n13",
          target: "n15"
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: "dagre",
    padding: 5
  }
}));


cy.unbind('click')
cy.bind('click', 'node', function(event) {
  // .union() takes two collections and adds both together without duplicates
  var connected = event.target
  connected = connected.union(event.target.predecessors())
  connected = connected.union(connected.successors())
  // in one line: 
  // event.target.union(event.target.predecessors().union(event.target.successors()))

  // .not() filters out whatever is not specified in connected, e.g. every other node/edge not present in connected
  var notConnected = cy.elements().not(connected)

  // if you want, you can later add the saved elements again
  var saved = cy.remove(notConnected)
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-dagre@2.1.0/cytoscape-dagre.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ah perfect! Surprisingly elegant solution.  Thanks Stephan.  

Separately are you aware of any community spaces for Cytoscape / Cytoscape.js? I can't find anything that looks like a chat, forum Slack channel or IRC.

Comment: Hmm seems this is it: `Questions about cytoscape.js should go to stackoverflow.`
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cytoscape-app-dev

Comment: I personally don't really participate in other communities than stackoverflow, but as you can see [here](https://blog.js.cytoscape.org/2017/06/13/contributing/#discussing-contributions), there are dedicated places for different scopes. Just see for yourself, which one suits your needs best :) Also, @maxkfranz, the lead developer of cytoscape.js, frequently answers questions about cytoscape.js here on stackoverflow, so I'd suggest the official documentation and this platform as your main knowledge source.

Comment: Ah gitter looks like the place :) Thanks again

Comment: I added a link to jsfiddle with the working version, if thats still a problem for you.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same but for undirected graph? Since sources/targets are randomly set in this case, successors/predecessors won't work