# Get recursively connected nodes in undirected graph in cytoscape & remove others

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have an undirected graph in cytoscape. Meaning that I still have sources/targets for every edge in data, but they are chosen randomly.

Now I need to display a cluster of nodes that contains one specified node, excluding others. So basically I need to get all connected nodes, and remove others.

How can I achieve that? I found a lot of methods for traversing the graph, like outgoures or succeeders but they are used for directed graph.

[image]

```js
let cy = cytoscape({
      container: document.getElementById('cy'),
      elements: [
        {
          data: {
            id: 1
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 2
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 3
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 4
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 5
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 6
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: '1-2',
            source: 1,
            target: 2
          },
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: '2-3',
            source: 2,
            target: 3
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: '3-4',
            source: 3,
            target: 4
          },
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: '6-5',
            source: 6,
            target: 5
          }
        }
      ]
})


// How to keep only the cluster of nodes which are connected to the magenta node, and remove other non-connected clusers? In undirected graph
const node = cy.getElementById(2);
node.style('background-color', 'magenta')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.17.1/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

<div id="cy" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: This can be done without recursion. Any code attempt? (so to choose a solution). Without recursion: have an array with a boolean on payload that tells you whether you visited that node. The same array could be used for the "expansion".

Comment: I was looking for some ready solutions in the documentation, one of the fancy solution was using predecessors/successors multiple times. But there should be some kind of function for undirected graphs, no?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59932853/filtering-graph-by-connectivity-to-a-specific-node-in-cytoscape-js  I tried this, but it works only for directed graphs

Comment: Please add your code as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise we would just throw solutions at you without any confirmation if they work.

Comment: Okay, I added an example, sorry.

Comment: As the developer of cytoscape.js said, if your graph is undirected, then it doesn't matter which node is specified as source and which node is specified as target. So there is really no difference in the solution you mentioned above and your problem. I tried out my code, you can use it as it is as far as I can tell.

Comment: A "directed" graph is just nodes, edges and the position of edge-endpoints (arrows). A "undirected" graph just consists of nodes and edges without edge-endpoints. Even in your code, you used source and target in the edge initialization.

Comment: In graph theory, that's called a component.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory) and https://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.components